# Page Numbering in R Bookdown

Tags: r, latex, bookdown

How do you  achieve roman numerals for things like preface, acknowledgement etc and restart Arabic numbering  at  1 for first page of chapter one in R Bookdown.

I am wanting to render to pdf in bookdown, but have not found any good information on how to change page numbering like this

thanks

Answer (score 15):

Please also look at [the answer by @maxheld](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48925547/8416610). It is simpler and for many use cases sufficient. Another simple solution that does not require editing the template would be:

```
---
title: Page Numbering in R Bookdown
documentclass: book
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book: default
header-includes:
- \AtBeginDocument{\frontmatter}
---
\mainmatter

# Header 1

Some text 

\backmatter

# Appendix 1

Some text
```

This inserts `\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter` and `\backmatter` in the right places.

---

#### Original answer

PDF output is produced with LaTeX using the `book` document class. In this class, you can use `\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter` and `\backmatter` to separate different 'parts' of the book. In order to use this with `bookdown` I did the following:

- start with a copy of https://github.com/seankross/bookdown-start
- copy `<R-library-path>/rmarkdown/rmd/latex/default-1.17.0.2.tex` as `book.tex` to the working directory
- update `book.tex` to include `\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter` and `\backmatter` (diff below)
- update `_output.yml` to refer to `book.tex` as `template` (diff below)

With these changes the PDF produced with `bookdown` used (loweercase) roman numerals for the ToC and restarted with arabic numbers for the actual body. Here the diff:

```
 diff --git a/_output.yml b/_output.yml
index 112cf5b..b211ba7 100644
--- a/_output.yml
+++ b/_output.yml
@@ -13,5 +13,6 @@ bookdown::pdf_book:
     in_header: preamble.tex
   latex_engine: xelatex
   citation_package: natbib
+  template: book.tex
 bookdown::epub_book:
   stylesheet: style.css
diff --git a/book.tex b/book.tex
index 0f9979d..3d03540 100644
--- a/book.tex
+++ b/book.tex
@@ -235,6 +235,9 @@ $header-includes$
 $endfor$

 \begin{document}
+$if(book-class)$
+\frontmatter
+$endif$
 $if(title)$
 \maketitle
 $endif$
@@ -263,8 +266,14 @@ $endif$
 $if(lof)$
 \listoffigures
 $endif$
+$if(book-class)$
+\mainmatter
+$endif$
 $body$

+$if(book-class)$
+\backmatter
+$endif$
 $if(natbib)$
 $if(bibliography)$
 $if(biblio-title)$
```

Answer (score 10):

I think it might be easier to just follow the example @yihui used in his own [bookdown `krantz` example](https://github.com/yihui/bookdown-crc):

Add the following files, perhaps in a `/latex` subfolder:

- `preamble.tex` with the latex `\frontmatter` command at the end,
- `after_body.tex` with the latex `\backmatter` command,

Then, before your first *actual* main body, just add the `\mainmatter` command (just in latex) to, say, your `index.Rmd` (whichever of your `*.Rmd`s is first, conventionally `index.Rmd`).

Then, to amend your `_output.yml` like so:

```
bookdown::pdf_book:
  includes:
    in_header: latex/preamble.tex
    after_body: latex/after_body.tex
```

This intersperses the correct `\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter` and `\backmatter` commands into your pandoc-ed latex book. It will be respected by most style files to make sure that arabic numbering only begins inside the main matter.

This is also documented in the [publishing chapter](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/publishers.html) of the bookdown book.

Comment: +1 since this is indeed much simpler. The only disadvantage is that the bibliography and any appendices are still part of \mainmatter. However, you can place \backmatter before the first appendix or at the end of the last chapter.

Answer (score 2):

It's actually very simple:

In the front matter part do this:

```
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{roman}
```

In the main matter part:

```
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
```